# Same Role with Different Profile

Tags: opportunity, profile, role-hierarchy

If I have to Sales Associates with same 'Role' but different 'Profile' will they be able to see their opportunities?

If they have same role and same profile, will they be able to see each others optys. Please suggest.

Comment: Its all depends on what permission you give them on their profile

Answer (score 3):

Actually Profile control object level access and role control record level access.
If you set Opportunity OWD as private they both will be able to see only their record either Role same and profile diff or role same and profile same.

Role define hierarchy level. If any user have higher level in hierarchy he can see lower level user record but in your scenario role are same they cannot see each other records if OWD private. If OWD public read only any one can see any other user opportunity.

Object, field level access control by Profile, permission set.
Record level access control by OWD permission, grant access using hierarchy, sharing rule.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through record Sharing rules. Salesforce has good videos on "Who sees what?" you should get enough knowledge on Salesforce record sharing by this videos.
[Who Sees What](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6747B4DAE356E17C)

Hope this works for you.

For the question you asked if the roles are same and so are profiles and the object has public read the records should get shared. If the profiles are different then object depending on the permissions profile has sharing will change accordingly.